# powershell - Ignore quotation marks in Add-Content text string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a PowerShell code to add some text in final of file, but my text has `""` on it

How can I make PowerShell fill everything in the final of text without conflicting with `""`?

The command itself:

```sh
Add-Content C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf -Value "`n<VirtualHost localhost:80>`n`tDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"`n`tServerName localhost`n`tServerAlias *.localhost`n </VirtualHost>`n<VirtualHost localhost:443>`n`tDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"`n`tServerName localhost`n`tServerAlias *.localhost`n`tSSLEngine on`n`tSSLCertificateFile "ssl/server.crt"`n`tSSLCertificateKeyFile "ssl/server.key"`n </VirtualHost>"
```

Should output:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias *.localhost
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost localhost:443>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias *.localhost
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile "ssl/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "ssl/server.key"
 </VirtualHost>
```

Screenshot of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Kxe.png

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text instead of screenshot, we will help you format it.

Comment: Doesn't look like any interpolation is happening. Why not just use single quotes? You can escape double quotes with another double quote (`""`), or with a backtick (`" )

Comment: Abraham, this didn't work, I already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when working with strings like you're doing, it's best to use [`Here-Strings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1#here-strings). By doing this you don't need to add `` `n `` for ***New Lines*** or `` `t `` for ***Tabulations***. You can simply format your text as you would like it to appear on the `.conf` file:

```
$hereString = @'
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost localhost:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "ssl/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "ssl/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
'@

Add-Content C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf -Value $hereString
```

Here is an example of how it looks:

- I create a new text file with the phrase 'Hello world!'

```
PS /> 'Hello World!' | Out-File test.txt
```

- Then I add the `$hereString` as displayed in the code above:

```
PS /> Add-Content .\test.txt -Value $hereString
```

- Last, get the content of the file, you will see the string we used as literal:

```
PS /> Get-Content .\test.txt
Hello World!
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost localhost:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "ssl/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "ssl/server.key"
</VirtualHost>"
```

Comment: how am I supposed to type it on Pwsh? also I want to make this into a batch file that will use the "powershell -c" command

Comment: it just doesn't go, looks the command completed successfully but nothing in file changed, I took a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/0pyHbUd.png

Comment: @brokenPipe if you were to execute this from cmd the best idea would be to save this as a `ps1` script and then from cmd call `powershell.exe -File "path\to\this\script.ps1"` you should have specified this in your question tho, I understand now why you were using that syntax.

Comment: @brokenPipe glad to know! happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

escape the " in the text with a tick; `"

like write-output "`""